# Kurento:One2one video call not reaching to the peer end

Tags: maven, kurento

I want to simulate kurento-one2one-call locally .

I Install the kurento media server which is running in same machine.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN      3022/kurento-media-
```

then I install the kurento-one2one-call by using below command

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-one2one-call
git checkout 6.7.1
mvn compile exec:java
```

then by opening the browser type https://localhost:8443 for user-1 and did same for user-2.

then register both user, when I am going to call from user-1 to user-2 by typing his name, I am not able to call.

Am I missing something in configuration part?

Any suggestion will great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

I see you did not mentioned anything about STUN configuration and it is an essential part to make it work. Like mentioned in the [installation guide](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installation.html) :

To configure a STUN server in KMS, uncomment the following lines in the WebRtcEndpoint configuration file, located at /etc/kurento/modules/kurento/WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini:

```
    stunServerAddress=<serverIp>
    stunServerPort=<serverPort>
```

In my case, I couldn't make it work with the listed Stun IPs in the installation guide so I configured a Coturn server following the steps at [kurento FAQ](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/faq.html). After installing Coturn successfully, you only need to edit stunServer part in the WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini properly to make it work locally.

Hope this helps.